# Breaking Timestamps into sessions by break in timestamps

Tags: python, sql, hadoop, hive

I have some log files that contain timestamp, id, and an action.  I have some example data below. The actual data is millions of rows long.  I'm hoping to group all of the actions that a users takes within a given session.  And a session can be defined as any continuous entry of logs (from a specific user) where the gap between the previous timestamp isn't more than 30 minutes.

```
timestamp             id    action
2014-06-30 21:57:16   234     1
2014-06-30 16:47:05   793     3
2014-06-30 16:47:15   793     1
2014-06-30 16:47:50   793     2
2014-06-30 16:48:07   793     5
2014-06-30 16:48:08   793     6
2014-06-30 16:48:48   793     7
2014-06-30 16:49:26   793     1
2014-06-30 16:49:28   993     3
2014-06-30 04:24:39   229     2
2014-06-30 21:53:38   822     4
```

I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. I'm sure this has been done before, but couldn't find anything online.  Think I'm searching for the wrong questions.

Looking for something SQL based.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server (microsoft), MySQL, or something else?

Comment: I'm actually in Hadoop.  So, Hive/Pig/Streaming.  But, I can put portions of the logs into Teradata if need be.

Comment: Yikes. I was hoping you'd say SQL Server. ;-)   In SQL Server land you could probably do something with an aggregate function and it wouldn't be too crazy complicated. I suppose I should have looked closer at your tags!

Comment: Well, I think I actually know what to search for now.  It looks like this is referred to as sessionization.  Looks like there is some articles if you Google "sessionize web log pig".  I'll post an answer once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write this but really quickly got pretty complex and unfortunately I dont work for free :). I can explain to you what you have to do instead.

Basically, you need to select a list of unique values from your ID column (I am assuming those are user ID's). You then need to loop through the list of ID's, one by one, and for each one, select a list of timestamps corresponding to that id, ordered ascending.

Then, you need to select the earliest time stamp, and compare it to the next timestamp in the ascending list, to see if the next one is < or > 30 minutes difference. If its <, store it, the ID, and the Action value in a new table, with an identifier to tag it as part of the session. Then take the 2nd timestamp, and compare it to the next time stamp in the list. If its <, store it and keep continuing through the list in this fashion. However, if the next value is > 30 minutes, generate a new unique session ID, and then continue on through the list.

Overall, this isnt something id recommend you do in sql, especially if youre planning to do it on some server thats in production somewhere and actively writing to this table, since youre going to cause some massive locks if its really that big. This is something that would be better done in an application layer somewhere if possible. If thats not possible, id recommend you copy the data into some temp tables before you start analyzing it.

If you plan on doing this more than once, id also probably recommend you see if its possible to add a session identifier to the data wherever its generated.